# How to safe cast int reference to long reference?

Tags: c++, c++17

Given

```
T& bindParam(const long& val) {
  /* some code*/
}
T& bindParam(const long&& val) = delete;

T& bindParam(const int& val) // same as above for int
{
    static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)); // true
    static_assert(alignof(int) == alignof(long)); // true
    return bindParam(reinterpret_cast<const long&>(val));
}
T& bindParam(const int&& val) = delete;
```

Clang says `warning : reinterpret_cast from 'const int' to 'const long &' has undefined behavior [-Wundefined-reinterpret-cast]` (obviously, strict aliasing violation, but should work if compiler is not intended to break code).

How to work around this without duplicating same code for `int` and templating this method is not desirable (changes overload resolution)?

Comment: I think the cast here may be problematic by itself if `long` has stricter alignment requirements than `int`.

Comment: `bindParam(*reinterpret_cast<const long*>(&val))`, but I would opt for a safer solution : `long tmp = val; bindParam(tmp);`

Comment: updated code, now checking aligment

Comment: @RemyLebeau I need reference to external variable, not local temporary

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic the `reinterpret_cast` using pointers instead of references would accomplish that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau why it should change anything? `warning : dereference of type 'const long *' that was reinterpret_cast from type 'const int *' has undefined behavior [-Wundefined-reinterpret-cast]`

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic: I'm curious as to why you delete rvalue-reference versions when you aren't modifying the value. Is there some reason why people shouldn't be allowed to pass a prvalue to this function?

Comment: @NicolBolas because it saved for later use. It should outlive call to this function.

Comment: No compiler is “intended to break code”, but much of the point of rules like these is that optimizing good code and breaking bad code are often indistinguishable to the compiler.

Comment: @DavisHerring UBsan was created for breaking bad code.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic: UBSan does the opposite: it optimizes/breaks *less* code so that bad code has *more* predictable/desirable behavior (namely, the runtime checking you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> obviously, strict aliasing violation, but should work if compiler is not intended to break code

If you don't care about strict aliasing violations, then you should ignore warnings that appear when you violate strict aliasing. Which is what this warning is doing.

Accessing a `long` through a pointer/reference to an `int` is a violation of the strict aliasing rule and is therefore UB. This is not an optional rule of C++; there is no in-language mechanism to ignore the rule.

If you have decided to ignore strict aliasing, apparently under the assumption that the compiler can be relied upon to make your code behave as you expect it to, then you should inform your compiler by turning off warnings about strict aliasing violations.

Comment: So if I have `struct A {};` and `struct B{};`, there is no way in C++ to pass B to `void f(A&);`, right? There are things like `std::is_layout_compatible` and `std::is_standard_layout`, giving me hope that something can be done.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic: No. That's what "strict aliasing" *means* (or rather, what it explicitly prohibits: aliasing one object as another).

Comment: I updated question with usage example. I only casting pointers(references) on my side and this is well defined.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic: Is what happens behind that function "well defined" too? How can it use that pointer without casting it to the correct type? But in any case, this doesn't change my answer: you're ultimately still violating strict aliasing, whether in C or in C++. Your choices are to either stop doing that or turn off the warning.

Comment: I came up with solution. See my answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/62940495/5647513 )

Answer (score 1):

> How to safe cast int reference to long reference?

#### On implementations where `sizeof(int)` is not `sizeof(long)` you cannot do that  safely.

And most x86-64 implementations have `sizeof(int)` being 4 bytes, and `sizeof(long)` being 8 bytes. You also want `alignof(int)` being equal to `alignof(long)`

See also the C++17 standard (or [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)).

Comment: there is `static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)); // true` just for that.
They are same on Win32 at least

Comment: So, is it possible to do this without triggering undefined behavior, assuming int == long?

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic: You are asking "can I break strict-aliasing"? The answer is "no"; it's not an optional rule of the C++ object model.